# Header not found in ios project created in objective c and xcode 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

I am trying to use cocoapods in my project. I have installed SimpleAuth and I can see its directory and files in pods folder, but when I import in appDelegate its showing:

> #import "SimpleAuth/SimpleAuth.h"     "SimpleAuth/SimpleAuth.h" file not found

[image]

[image]

I'm new in iOS development, please help me.

Comment: try to update pod using terminal

Comment: Which version of Xcode/Swift are you using?

Comment: i am using Objective c and Xcode 7